# No makefile error after running ./configure yet there is clearly a makefile in the dir

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, bison

[image: From the top of the terminal you can see the program being configured. At the bottom you can see I try to run the make file but it says there is not one. I run ls and there is clearly a makefile right there in the directory.]

Before you tell me to read some wiki or installation guide, I already have read multiple and followed them step by step word for word.

I ran ./configure already
I have gcc and cc installed.

Comment: Is the `m4` package installed on your system? FYI neither `Makefile.am` nor `Makefile.in` are makefiles

Comment: "you must run ./configure" Did you? What was the result? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I ran ./configure and I have cc and gcc.

Comment: @steeldriver I will install the m4 package and see if it works.

Comment: @chili555 the top of my picture has the results of ./configure it ran as I expected it to.

Comment: @steeldriver after installing m4 make is working.  Thank you.  I have another question why must I run ./configure as sudo and make as sudo?  If I don't it says permission denied.

Comment: It stopped working again I don't know why.  This time trying to install gcc...  I have downloaded the tar.gz and unpacked it then ran ./configure and it's telling me I have no makefile again.

Comment: Followed another isntallation guide and it's working.

Comment: @Aplleroar why are you trying to compile `bison` from source code? Do you want to learn something, what are the specifics? The `bison` is [packaged in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bison), so you can simply install it from precompiled deb-package to save time and prevent compilation issues...

Comment: @N0rbert On the gcc website the guide for downloading it said bison was required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are solving problems on source code level while all necessary development stuff is pre-compiled in deb-package form.

So you can install build tools by:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison libbison-dev
```

Other development stuff may be found using search on https://packages.ubuntu.com - provide *name* of package and *dev* suffix to sort out the things. Next install the package by using APT - something like `sudo apt-get install name-dev`.

Comment: Thank you but build-essential does not contain gcc10.2 which was what I needed.  I have installed m4 package and I can run make now.